# Custom domain goes to gitlab not correct page

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, gitlab

I have a working Gitlab instance setup as follows:

Internet -> Nginx Reverse Proxy (all traffic) -> Gitlab Docker Container (1080:80, 1443:443)

Pages works as expected on https with the following settings:

```
pages_external_url "https://pages.example.com/"
gitlab_pages['enable'] = true
gitlab_pages['external_http'] = ['127.0.0.1:1080']
gitlab_pages['external_https'] = ['127.0.0.1:1443']
pages_nginx['enable'] = true
pages_nginx['redirect_http_to_https'] = true
pages_nginx['ssl_certificate'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/fullchain.pem"
pages_nginx['ssl_certificate_key'] = "/etc/gitlab/ssl/privkey.pem"
```

(Ports specified are inside the container and are not exposed)

I.e. I can access the pages site at `https://username.pages.example.com`

This is all one server with one dynamic IP all addresses are pointed to the one server.

I am trying to use `https://example.com` as the secondary address for the pages site.
The gitlab instance should be on `https://git.example.com/`

I've been trying to mess with the `gitlab_pages['listen_proxy']` setting but it never listens from what I can tell.

There are no errors in the gitlab log that I can see.

As in the title, the problem I'm having is that `https://example.com` gives the gitlab interface, not the pages site.

Let me know if you need any more information, logs etc.